# Need help implementing a Doubly Linked List in Java[Final]

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

Hello guys thanks for all the help thus far I have pretty much finished this project.

Now ill explain my code and the special features i had to implement.
1. My linked list has to start with a specific amount of elements, youll see this in the dll constructor
2. a method that input new values into the elements created.
3. i have a get method to get the value at a certain node. this also creates new nodes if the user calls an index value greater then the list size
4. i also created an insert method that inserts an element to a specific location.

My node class looks like this(sorry for the lowercase class name):

```
public class node {

private int _value;

public node(int v){
    _value = v;
}

public node(){

}

public int get(){
    return _value;
}

public void set(int v){
    _value = v;
}

public node next = null;
public node prev = null;
}
```

My DLL class (odd name i know just the title of the project) :

```
public class BetterArray{

private int _size;
private node _head;
private node _tail;

public BetterArray(int n){
    _head = null;
    _tail = null;
    _size = n;

    if(_head == null){
        _head = new node(0);
        _tail = _head;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        node current = _head;
        for(int j = 1; j < i; j++){
            current = current.next;
        }
        node newNode = current.next;
        current.next = new node(0);
        current.next.next = newNode; 
        current.next.prev = current;
        _tail = current.next;
    }
}   

public BetterArray(){           
}

public int get(int index){
    int value = 0;
    node temp = _head;
    if(index < _size){
        for(int loc = 0; loc < index; loc++){
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        value = temp.get();
    }
    else{
        for(int i = _size; i <= index; i++){
            node current = temp;
            for(int j = _size; j < i; j++){
                current = current.next;
            }
            node newNode = current.next;
            current.next = new node(0);
            _size++;
            current.next.next = newNode; 
            current.next.prev = current;
            _tail = current.next;
        }
    }
    return value;
}   

public void put(int value, int index){
    node temp = _head;
    if(index < _size){
        for(int loc = 0; loc < index; loc++){
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.set(value);
    }
    else{
        for(int i = _size; i < index; i++){
            node current = temp;
            for(int j = _size; j < i; j++){
                current = current.next;
            }
            node newNode = current.next;
            current.next = new node(value);
            _size++;
            current.next.next = newNode; 
            current.next.prev = current;
            _tail = current.next;           
        }
    }   
}

public void insert(int value,int index){
    node current = _head;

        for(int loc = 0; loc < index - 1; loc++){
            current = current.next;
        }

        node temp = current.next;
        current.next = new node(value);
        _size++;
        current.next.next = temp;
        current.next.prev = current;
        _tail = current.next;
    }   
}

public void delete(int index){
    node pre = _head;

    for(int loc = 0; loc < index; loc++){
        pre = pre.next;
    }
    node current = pre.next;
    pre.next = current.next;
    _size--;
}
public int getSize(){
    return _size;
}
```

Comment: Creating a linked list with N elements without values makes no sense. My recommendation is that you don't do that. If you have to, just call `add(null)` N times, since you have to implement `add()` anyway.

Comment: @andreas i believe that is what the insert method is for or is my logic wrong here

Comment: Please note that its clearer if you have also the class name `node` starting with a capital, thus `Node`. The insert method is to create a new node with a value.

Comment: @martijnn2008 And `BetterArray` is a lousy name for a doubly-linked-list implementation.

Comment: @Andreas  can you please leave comments regarding my questions instead of my naming convention. thank you

Comment: When you get an index to insert at that's bigger than the size, I'd recommend throwing an out of bounds exception like an Arraylist would do. You're wasting memory by filling up the list with empty nodes

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the feedback but this is how it has to be done and im still having troubles accomplishing the goal. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what the actual question is

Comment: @cricket_007 ok so basically i have to make a condition in my insert method that says if the index is greater then the size of the list to expand the list to accommodate the new element. im tryinf to use a while loop instead of the for loop ill update the thread shortly. in the meantime do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well, the sample code of that method you posted just calls the Node constructor and doesn't really do anything with that, so my suggestion is to actually hook up the pointers to insert nodes. And I believe a for loop would work because you want to loop until you hit the index to insert at

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the suggestion i was literally about to try to do a for loop seems to make the most sense ill update the thread with what you said in mind

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Now that I better understand what you want (an arbitrarily-indexed insertion function for a doubly-linked list data structure), here's some code that might help you:

```
public class BetterArray{

    public node _head = null;
    public node _tail = null;

    public BetterArray(){
        _head = _tail = new node();
    }

    public node insert(int val, int index) {
        if (index < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must provide an index which is not negative");
        }
        node current = _head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (current.next == null) {
                current.next = new node();
                current.next.prev = current;
                _tail = current;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.set(val);
        return current;
    }
}

public class node {

    private int _value;
    private boolean _initialized;

    public node(int v){
        _value = v;
        _initialized = true;
    }

    public node(){
        _initialized = false;
    }

    public int get(){
        if (!_initialized) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This node has not been set with any value");
        }
        return _value;
    }

    public void set(int v){
        _value = v;
        _initialized = true;
    }

    public node next = null;
    public node prev = null;
}
```

You can try it out, too. Just do something like this:

```
BetterArray whatever = new BetterArray();
whatever.insert(5,3);
System.out.println(whatever._head.next.next.next.get());
```

Just so you know, there is also standard Java data structures already implemented. You may want to take a look at [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). Basically what I'm doing would be the same as adding nodes until its size prevents it from getting an `IllegalArgumentException`, then doing a `set`.

ORIGINAL POST:

Linked lists and Arrays are two completely different data structures. Rather than focusing on the implementation, think about what you want to do with the data structure. Need random access to data? A (doubly) linked list will take O(n) time to find the right element for both reads and writes; you've seen this yourself with the logic you've implemented in the insert. For arrays, random access is a O(1) constant time operation. If you want to write a data structure like a List to have random access, try using `new node[n]`, and hold the entire array object privately in memory.

If something is greater, the standard practice is to create a new array twice the size of the index asked for and copy all of the old data into the new array. This is a O(n) operation, whereas insertion for a linked list at the beginning or end of the list is O(1) constant time.

Is there a middle ground? Actually there is! If you implement a balanced binary tree, you can get O(lg(n)) insert and O(lg(n)) access to your nodes. I recommend you brush up on your data structures. Try doing it out on pencil and paper until you understand how the structures feel, then put it to code. Unless you're comfortable with Java or it's required by your class, stick with whatever language you learned first (I'm assuming C because of the style you write and the way you call things "pointers"). Otherwise you'll be learning two things at the same time, which is generally harder than learning one thing at a time.

Comment: How does this answer the problem of *I need to implement a doubly linked list*?

Comment: Why? And what operations do you need for your list object?

Comment: I was just stating that pointing out that there are differences in data structures doesn't help answer how to implement the function that was asked about in the question.

Comment: It's an object, a data structure, not a function. If anything it is a collection of functions/operations. And you need to specify what operations you need for this linked list data structure, otherwise you won't be able to fully implement it. It would also be helpful to know what running time you expect from those operations: are you okay with scanning through the whole linked list to find something?

Comment: The question that was buried in the original post.. "My insert method compiles fine but i want to make sure that i set all the pointers properly if anyone could check that over for me". So, the `insert` function for the Doubly Linked List object that was trying to be implemented in the question was not working as expected. Nothing about arrays or trees needed to be mentioned... That's my point

Comment: Okay, I edited the post with an insert function like asked for.